# Generate an account code for SAGE Accounting allows 9 but need it to stop at 8

Tags: apex, trigger

```
/*
Updated by PAH 2013-05-29 to set the Sage_Account_Name__c to a unique Name that can be used by Sage

need to add is isInsert and keep old code in teh isUpdate
*/

//trigger ownerLookup on Account (before Insert, before Update) {
trigger ownerLookup on Account (before Insert, before Update) 
{   
    system.debug('############### ownerLookup just started ');

   if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && UtilityClassForLeadConversion.isAvoid)
   {
    for(Account x : Trigger.New)
    {
        // check that owner is a user (not a queue)
        x.Owner_Lookup__c = x.OwnerId;
    }


    Map<string,Account> accountMap = new Map<string,Account>();
    for(Account thisacc : [select Sage_Account_Name__c, Name, Id from Account limit 49990])
    {
        accountMap.put(thisacc.Sage_Account_Name__c, thisacc);
    }
    system.debug('############### accountMap =' + accountMap  );

    //if (trigger.isInsert)
    //{
        system.debug('############### ownerLookup is insert ');
        for(Account x : Trigger.New)
        {
            system.debug('############### this account x =' + x);
            //Map<string,Account> accountMap = new Map<string,Account>();
            //for(Account thisacc : [select Sage_Account_Name__c, Name, Id from Account])
            //{
            //  accountMap.put(thisacc.Sage_Account_Name__c, thisacc);
            //}

            if (x.Sage_Account_Name__c == null ||  x.Sage_Account_Name__c == '')
            {
                string accountnumbertouse = x.Name;

                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.toUpperCase();
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);

                if (accountnumbertouse.startsWith('THE')) accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(3);
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);


                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.replaceAll(' ', '');
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);
                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.replaceAll('_', '');
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);
                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.replaceAll('-', '');
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);
                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.replaceAll(',', '');
                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);
                accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.replaceAll('\\.', '');

                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse after trim and remove space =' + accountnumbertouse);

                if (accountnumbertouse.length() >= 8) accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(0,6);

                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);


                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 2) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '000001';
                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 3) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '00001';
                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 4) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '0001';
                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 5) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '001';
                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 6) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '01';
                if (accountnumbertouse.length() == 7) accountnumbertouse =  accountnumbertouse + '1';

                system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse after adding padding =' + accountnumbertouse);

                Boolean accountnameisunique = false;
                system.debug('############### accountnameisunique =' + accountnameisunique); 
                integer uniquenumber = 1;
                system.debug('############### uniquenumber =' + uniquenumber); 

                while (!accountnameisunique)
                {
                    if(accountMap.containsKey(accountnumbertouse)) {
                    // do foo
                        system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse is already there...');
                        uniquenumber ++;
                        system.debug('############### uniquenumber =' + uniquenumber); 
                        if (uniquenumber < 10) accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(0,6) + '0' + string.valueOf(uniquenumber);
                        else accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(0,6) + string.valueOf(uniquenumber);
                        system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse =' + accountnumbertouse);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        system.debug('############### accountnumbertouse is unique');
                        accountnameisunique = true;
                        system.debug('############### accountnameisunique =' + accountnameisunique); 
                    }
                }


                system.debug('############### accountnameisunique =' + accountnameisunique); 
                x.Sage_Account_Name__c = accountnumbertouse;

            }

        //}

    }

     UtilityClassForLeadConversion.isAvoid = false;
     system.debug('############### ownerLookup just finished ');
   }    
}
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly what is your code doing and what you are trying to achieve? I cannot understand much from the title

Comment: The code is something I've inherited from before I was here. 
It basically is generating an 8 digit reference code using the account name then a rolling number after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear,but try changing the following lines accordingly:

```
 if (accountnumbertouse.length() >= 7) accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(0,6);   // it was 8 instead of 7 before

 if (uniquenumber < 9) accountnumbertouse = accountnumbertouse.substring(0,6) + '0' + string.valueOf(uniquenumber);   // it was 10 instead of 9
```